# Ubuntu 16.04 can't change HDMI resolution, no HDMI-1 in xrandr

Tags: display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a HDMI monitor hooked up to my PC running Ubuntu 16.04. It's working in the sense that I can see the desktop on the monitor. I went into the "Displays" settings to try and change the resolution to 1920x1080, but the only option available is 1024x768. I went down the google rabbit hole of debugging, and tried to use the `xrandr` command to change some things. For one, this is the output of `xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00*
```

The consensus is that I should see something obvious as "HDMI-1" or such, instead of "default". This doesn't seem quite right, but since I am getting some kind of HDMI signal, I assumed "default" was the HDMI-1 signal. Continuing on, I then added a new resolution mode:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then assign the mode to my display "default":

```
sudo xrandr --addmode default "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Now I go back into Monitor settings, and I can now select 1920x1080, but when I try to apply the settings I get an error message:

```
The selected configuration for displays could not be applied. required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(1920, 1080), minimum=(1024, 768), maximum=(1024, 768)
```

As a side note, I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get update`. Still no luck. I then booted the same PC into Windows 10 and verified that I could get the correct resolution, without making any hardware changes.

Any help changing the screen resolution?

Comment: I've done this but I never used `sudo`. What video card and driver are you using?

Comment: No specific video card, just Integrated Graphics: AMD Radeon RX Vega 11 Graphics